# tree structure on classes of elements in GL_2 over a field with discrete valuation

Tags: group-theory, trees, valuation-theory

this is my first question here, so I hope I am doing it right. :)

I'm currently reading a paper about the tree of GL_2 over a discretely valued field (similarly to Serre). Here's the setting:

$k$ an arbitrary field

$t$ local parameter (to a valuation $\nu$)

$\Theta_\infty := k[[t]]$ ($=$ the valuation ring to $\nu$)

$G := GL_2(k((t))), K := GL_2(\Theta_\infty), Z := $ the centre of $G$

Let $G/KZ$ be the vertex set of the tree. (the adjacency relation doesn't play a role for my question) Then two vertices $gKZ$ and $hKZ$ are equal iff $h^{-1}g \in KZ$. However, I have two given vertices of which ones I am sure that they are not equal (they are adjacent):

\begin{align*}
o &:= \begin{pmatrix} t & t^{-1} \\  & 1 \end{pmatrix}KZ \\
v &:= \begin{pmatrix} t^2 & t^{-1} + lt \\  & 1 \end{pmatrix}KZ \text{ (for some $l \in k$).}
\end{align*}

I calculate
$$
o^{-1}v = \begin{pmatrix} 
 t & l \\
   & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

But this matrix is in $GL_2(\Theta_\infty) = K$, isn't it? The $t$-valuations of the entries are: $\begin{pmatrix} = 1 & = 0 \\ = \infty & = 0 \end{pmatrix}$. It would follow that $oKZ = vKZ$ which can't be.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Everything you have written down seems reasonable to me.  Why are you sure the vertices aren't equal?

Comment: @HughThomas: Well, actually the adjacency relation is: $gKZ \sim hKZ :<=> h^{-1}g = \begin{pmatrix} t & b \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix} \mod KZ$ for some $b \in k$ or $= \begin{pmatrix} t^{-1} &  \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix} \mod KZ$. So the vertices above are adjacent. And if my above reasoning was true, the tree would consist of only 1 vertex. In addition to that, if they would be equal, the whole paper would kind of make no sense (the fundamental domain of the tree is calculated in the paper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, that took me too long.  The point is that $o^{-1}\nu$ is not in $K$, because its inverse is not a matrix with entries in $\Theta_\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! (The matrix is also not in KZ)